# Django wrong endpoint accessed by URL

Tags: python, django

I have 2 URL patterns in my Django application:

```
url_patterns = [
    url(r'test/read/all/', TestViews.test_read_all),
    url(r'test/read/all/custom/', TestViews.test_read_all_custom)
]
```

My problem is: when i try to access `test/read/all/custom/` URL, request are directed to `test/read/all/` URL (`TestViews.test_read_all` are triggered instead of `TestViews.test_read_all_custom`)

### EDIT

Both endpoint methods has the same api view decorator (`@api_view(["GET"])`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the end of string symbol '$' in the end of the url:

```
url(r'^test/read/all/$', TestViews.test_read_all),
```